# Python 3.3 Appcrash QtCore4.dll

Tags: python, qt, pyside, crash

Im trying to compile this Python3.3-Code provided by:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fqK8N48kPXs&feature=c4-overview-vl&list=PLA955A8F9A95378CE

I have installed QT 4.8.4 VS2012, PySide 1.1.2, python 3.3, Qt 5

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import time

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

try:
    #Default Values
    due = QTime.currentTime()
    message = "Alert!"

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        raise ValueError

    hours, minutes = sys.argv[1].split(":")
    due = QTime(int(hours), int(minutes))

    if not due.isValid():
        raise ValueError

    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        message = " ".join(sys.argv[2:])

        #python firstTutorial.py 15:36 This is my message

except ValueError:
    message = "Usage: firstTutorial.py HH:MM [optional message]" #24 hour clock


while QTime.currentTime() < due:
    time.sleep(10)

label = QLabel("<font color=red size=72><b>" +  message + "</b></font>")
label.setWindowFlags(Qt.SplashScreen) #Keine Fenstereigenschaften nutzen
label.show()

QTimer.singleShot(20000, app.quit) #20 seconds till quit SIGNAL/SLOT
app.exec_()
```

But I get a Python Appcrash, after I give the parameter like: "15:23"

> Problemsignatur:   Problemereignisname:   APPCRASH
>   Anwendungsname:   python.exe   Anwendungsversion: 0.0.0.0
>   Anwendungszeitstempel:    5194070d   Fehlermodulname: QtCore4.dll
>   Fehlermodulversion:   4.8.4.0   Fehlermodulzeitstempel:   50eb4eec
>   Ausnahmecode: c0000005   Ausnahmeoffset:  0000000000033810
>   Betriebsystemversion: 6.2.9200.2.0.0.256.49   Gebietsschema-ID:   1031
>   Zusatzinformation 1:  c436   Zusatzinformation
>   2:    c436a4fc38414d2d1792ffc3e15f3c19   Zusatzinformation 3: 664a
>   Zusatzinformation 4:  664a8423adc2000b0b283f71335a059d

Reinstalled QT, Python and PySide, but nothing worked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where does it crash? Have you stepped through?

Comment: well the Debugger doesnt work for me. As soon as I run the file it crashes. Without any commandline parameters the Programm works fine for me.